# how to change a array of a single column to a row of values instead of arrays in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, transpose

I am trying to convert an array of arrays that each contain only one integer to a single array with just the integers.

This is my code below. k=1 after the first for loop and the next code deletes all the rows of except the first one and then transposes it.

```
handles.Background = np.zeros(((len(imgY) * len(imgX)),len(imgZ)))
WhereIsBackground = np.zeros((len(imgY), len(imgX)))
k = 0
for i in range(len(imgY)):
    for j in range (len(imgX)):
        if img[i,j,handles.PS_Index] < (handles.PS_Mean_Intensity / 8):
            handles.Background[k,:] = img[i,j,:]
            WhereIsBackground[i,j] = 1
            k = k+1

handles.Background = np.delete(handles.Background,np.s_[k:(len(imgY)*len(imgX))+1],0).T
```

At this point, I can access data by using `handles.Background[n]` but this returns an array that contains a single integer. I was trying to convert the `handles.Background` so that when I do `handles.Background[n]`, it just returns a single integer instead of an array containing that value.
So, I'm getting `array([0.])` when I run `handles.Background[0]`, but I want to get just `0` when I run `handles.Background[0]`

I've observed that `int(handles.Background[i])` returns an integer and tried to reassign them using a for loop but the result didn't really change. What would be the best option for me?

```
    for i in range (len(handles.Background)):
        handles.Background[i] = int(handles.Background[i])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if `handles.Background[n]` returns an array, you can index into that, too, using the same [n] notation.

So you are looking for

```
handles.Background[n][0]
```

If you want to unpack the whole array at once, you can use this:

```
handles.Background = [bg[0] for bg in handles.Background]
```

Comment: So, I tried to unpack the whole array but it just turned it to a list with a single value 0. How would you convert this to an array that still contains all the values (there are about 100000 values in handles.Background)

Comment: If the data is laid out in the way described in your original question, the last line of my answer should do the trick. If you need it packed back into a numpy array, use

`handles.Background = np.fromiter(bg[0] for bg in handles.Background, dtype=int, count=handles.Background.size())`